# ¿Hay alguna carpeta de "shutdown"?

Tags: windows7

En Windows existe una carpeta llamada Inicio, o Startup en Inglés; en la ruta *%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup*, la cual se ejecuta al iniciar el sistema operativo. Mi pregunta es si existe una carpeta que se ejecute al apagar el sistema.
Gracias

Comment: Las carpetas no se *ejecutan*, lo que se ejecuta es el programa almacenado en dicha carpeta o el programa al que apunte el acceso directo almacenado en dicha carpeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No como tal. Pero si necesitas realizar una acción o ejecutar un programa al apagar el equipo puedes crear una tarea con el **Programador de tareas** de Windows y usar como desencadenador el cierre de sesión.

Te dejo [esta liga](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-ejecutar-autom%C3%A1ticamente-un/670d70fd-5000-4986-adf1-d2696998fc0a) donde puedes ver más información al respecto. Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Considero que no es equivalente, ya que puede cerrarse sesión sin apagar el equipo.

Comment: Es cierto, pero es la única posibilidad que se me ocurre puede funcionar y la única que permite Windows. Igual, si apagas el equipo cierras la sesión así que funciona en ese ámbito.

Comment: No es la única posibilidad, existen los scripts de inicio / apagado en las políticas de grupo. Sin embargo la pregunta no parece muy relacionada con el tema del sitio.

Comment: Vale, lo miraré

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder